# How to manage connection and command object with multiple threads

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm a novice C# dev and I'm writing a database app the performs updates on two different tables and inserts on another two tables and each process is running on it's own separate thread. So I have two threads handling inserts on two different tables and two threads handling updates on two different tables. Each process is updating and inserting approximately 4 or 5 times per second so I don't close the connection until the complete session is over then I close the entire app. I wanted to know if I should be closing the connection after each insert and update even though I'm preforming these operations so frequently. 2nd, should I have each thread running on it's own connection and command object.

By the way I'm writing the app in C# and the database is MySQL. Also, as of now I'm using one connection and command object for all four threads. I keep getting an error message saying "There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection that must be closed first", that's why I'm asking if I should be using multiple connection and command objects.

Thanks

-Donld

Comment: Why would you need to write anything to a database every 4 or 5 seconds. Is it necessary, really?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, presumably because his code has produced (or indeed received from the "outside world") 4 or 5 *somethings* every second that need to be persisted to the database? =)

Comment: @Rob: And to that I say: ...caching?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, seriously? Caching data that needs to be persisted in memory? Not knowing the OPs system I have to generalise, but if I'm receiving data from the outside world and not persisting it to the database immediately, what happens if I crash, or the machine blows up? Lost data. Last time I checked that was a bad thing =)

Comment: I would still have to go against the grain here, it's totally dependent on the nature of the data, hence my question of necessity.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable [connection pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html), it should enable optimal use of MySql connections for your scenario. Either way, generally the best pattern to follow is:

- Acquire and open connection
- Do work
- Close/release connection

Something similar to (I'm a bit rusty on the class names for the MySql connector, so this may not be *exactly* correct, but you should get the general idea!):

```
private void DoMyPieceOfWork(int value1, int value2)
{
    using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(
      CONNECTION_STRING_GOES_HERE))
    {   
        connection.Open();
        using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(
          "INSERT INTO TABLE `blah` (Column1, Column2) VALUES @column1, @column2"))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@column1", MySqlType.Int).Value = value1; 
            command.Parameters.Add("@column2", MySqlType.Int).Value = value2; 
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();   
    }
}
```

Of course this is a contrived, simplistic, example but the gist of it stands.

Comment: hey rob so you're suggesting that I "DO" follow standard practice of opening and closing my connection obj but instead of "trying" to manage the threads myself use thread pooling? and that should work just fine...

Comment: Yes, I'm recommending exactly that. Start with what's provided for you (i.e. connection pooling) and measure its effectiveness. Then, and only then, "roll your own" solution if you need to. The people who wrote the MySql .net connector (for all its failings! Though it's a lot better now than it was 2 years ago) are much more likely to "get it right" than you or I =)

Answer (score 0):

you have either to create a new connection for each thread, or (it's an idea) create a synchronized queue of command. Then process the queue in a single working thread.

You may also take a look as the Task class of the .Net framework 4